# Tomcat 10 is not locating WebApplicationInitializer in Spring MVC Maven project at startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to set up a simple Spring MVC Maven project with `WebApplicationInitializer`, but when I deploy the project on Tomcat 10, the `WebApplicationInitializer` is not getting loaded, it is not coming up in logs and not getting called.

**pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.springmvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvc-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>mvc-app Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>mvc-app</finalName>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Initializer**

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<test>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    }
}
```

**Tomcat Logs**

```
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.13
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 9 2021 22:12:58 UTC
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 10.0.13.0
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Users\sk464\Downloads\eclipse-jee-2021-03-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_16.0.1.v20210528-1205\jre
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           16.0.1+9-24
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.13
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.13
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.13
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.13
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.13\webapps
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.31] using APR version [1.7.0].
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021]
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [1238] milliseconds
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.13]
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.13\webapps\docs]
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.13\webapps\docs] has finished in [28] ms
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.13\webapps\examples]
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@35f7969d')
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.13\webapps\examples] has finished in [373] ms
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.13\webapps\host-manager]
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.13\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [45] ms
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.13\webapps\manager]
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.13\webapps\manager] has finished in [39] ms
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.13\webapps\ROOT]
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.13\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [27] ms
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 25, 2021 9:13:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [2103] milliseconds
```

**Project Structure**

[image]

**Tomcat Settings**

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try to reload all the dependencies again, that might help you.

Comment: Tomcat10 is JakartaEE not JavaEE and Spring (Boot) isn't compatible with JakartaEE yet. Use Tomcat 9 (which is the same as Tomcat10 but JavaEE instead of JakartaEE).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks! I wasn't aware about that. Working now.